# Identity Matrix in relativity

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor

What is the identity matrix in relativity? Is it diag(1, 1, 1, 1) or diag (-1, 1, 1, 1)? I am getting a bit confused about different vector notations actually.

Comment: Don't talk about matrices. The natural math tools for Physics are tensors. And component of tensors are not enough to define it, if you don't say the basis they are referred to

Comment: The identity tensor ought to be independent of basis.

Comment: @KyleKanos as all the tensors are.

Comment: @basics Pretty sure he means that the representation of the identity is independent of the basis.

Answer (score 4):

This is where index up versus index down becomes important. The identity is
\begin{align}
  \delta^\mu_{\hphantom{\mu}\nu} = \text{diag}(1,1,1,1)
\end{align}
Notice: one index is up (contravariant) and the other is down (covariant).

The Minkowski metric tensor is
\begin{align}
  \eta_{\mu\nu} = \text{diag}(-1,1,1,1),
\end{align}
depending on sign convention (particle physicists like $\text{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$). The metric tensor is the primary way to map a contravariant 4-vector to covariant one, and vice-versa for the inverse tensor.

You can think of the metric tensor as being a generalization of the transpose for column/row vectors. If a column vector is one with index up components, a row vector has index down. The transpose, itself, involves interchanging two indices, so this is just an analogy that only works for rank 1 tensors (vectors). When you get to higher rank tensors, raising and lowering indices can be done individually, without reference to other indices.

As defined above, the $\eta$ has both indices down (covariant). That's because what defines it is: $\mathrm{d}s^2 = \eta_{\mu\nu} \,\mathrm{d}x^\mu\,\mathrm{d}x^\nu$.

The definition of the inverse metric tensor $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is
$$ \eta^{\mu\alpha}\eta_{\alpha\nu} = \delta^\mu_{\hphantom{\mu}\nu}.$$

The reason for the naming convention covariant/contravariant is how the quantity varies in comparison to the basis vectors. If we define the full position 4-vector as
$$x = x^\mu \hat{e}_\mu$$
then in order for the vector itself to be invariant under Lorentz transformations the quantity $x^\mu$ has to vary in the opposite fashion as the basis vectors $\hat{e}_\mu$. Similarly, the differential of a scalar function $\mathrm{d}\phi$ has to be invariant. A simple exercise in calculus shows that
$$\mathrm{d}\phi = \mathrm{d}x^\mu \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^\mu}.$$
That tells you that the operator $\frac{\partial }{\partial x^\mu}$ has to be covariant to the basis vectors (in fact, some resources define the partial derivatives as the basis vectors). That's why we often write $\frac{\partial }{\partial x^\mu} = \partial_\mu$ with the index down.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

Physics equations are tensor equations. You can think as a tensor as a collection of symbols (the components) that follow precise rules of transformations under change of basis. For tensors of order-2, you can collect theae symbols in matrices, **but you have to keep in mind that they are referred to elements of a basis of a vector/tensor space**.

The matrices you're talking about are matrices that collect the components of metric tensor (we'll find that this tensor corresponds to the identity), using two different bases. Using vector product basis of the same vector basis, the components of the metric tensor could take a diagonal form, $\eta_{\alpha\beta}=\eta^{\alpha\beta}=diag(-1,1,1,1)$, while using vector product basis with one vector of a basis and one of its dual, you get $\eta^{\alpha}_{\beta} = \delta^{\alpha}_{\beta} = diag(1,1,1,1)$.

### Some details about tensors

**Ortonormal bases of Minkowski spacetime.**
Let's start from a orthonormal basis vector of Minkowski spacetime, $\{\mathbf{Q}_0, \mathbf{Q}_1, \mathbf{Q}_2, \mathbf{Q}_3\}$. Unlike Euclidean spaces, not all the dimensions have the same nature. This becomes evident defining the psuedo-inner product for spacetime, being $0$ the "time dimension"

$\mathbf{Q}_0 \cdot \mathbf{Q}_0 = -1$
$\mathbf{Q}_i \cdot \mathbf{Q}_i = 1, \quad i = 1:3$
$\mathbf{Q}_\alpha \cdot \mathbf{Q}_\beta = 0, \quad \alpha \ne \beta$,

and summarize these equations as

$\mathbf{Q}_{\alpha} \cdot \mathbf{Q}_{\beta} = \eta_{\alpha\beta} \qquad (1)$

Given the basis $\{\mathbf{Q}_0, \mathbf{Q}_1, \mathbf{Q}_2, \mathbf{Q}_3\}$, we can define the dual basis $\{\mathbf{Q}^0, \mathbf{Q}^1, \mathbf{Q}^2, \mathbf{Q}^3\}$ so that

$\mathbf{Q}_{\alpha} \cdot \mathbf{Q}^{\beta} = \delta_{\alpha}^{\beta} \qquad (2)$

The pseudo-inner products of the vectors of the dual basis can be summarised as

$\mathbf{Q}^{\alpha} \cdot \mathbf{Q}^{\beta} = \eta^{\alpha\beta} \qquad (3)$

**Relations between the vectors a basis and its dual.**
It's not difficult to prove that the following relations hold

$\mathbf{Q}^{\alpha} = \eta^{\alpha\beta}\mathbf{Q}_{\beta} \qquad (4)$
$\mathbf{Q}_{\alpha} = \eta_{\alpha\beta}\mathbf{Q}^{\beta} \qquad (5)$.

Let's prove the first one. By multiplying both sides of the equations with the pseudo-inner product with $\mathbf{Q}^{\gamma}$ we get

$\underbrace{\mathbf{Q}^{\gamma} \cdot \mathbf{Q}^{\alpha}}_{=\eta^{\alpha\gamma}} = \underbrace{\eta^{\alpha\beta}\mathbf{Q}_{\beta} \cdot\mathbf{Q}^{\gamma}}_{\eta^{\alpha\beta}\delta_\beta^\gamma=\eta^{\alpha\gamma}}$

**Some properties.**
Inserting (5) (using dummy index $\gamma$ instead of $\beta$) in (2), we get

$\delta_{\alpha}^{\beta} = \mathbf{Q}_{\alpha} \cdot \mathbf{Q}^{\beta} = \eta_{\alpha\gamma}\mathbf{Q}^{\gamma} \cdot \mathbf{Q}^{\beta} =\eta_{\alpha\gamma} \eta^{\gamma\beta} $

**Metric tensor and identity tensor.**
These relations could be collected in what is defined the metric tensor $\mathbb{\eta}\hspace{-4pt}\mathbb{\eta} = \eta_{\alpha \beta}\mathbf{Q}^\alpha\mathbf{Q}^\beta =\underbrace{\eta_{\alpha\beta}\eta^{\alpha \gamma}}_{=\delta_\beta^\gamma} \mathbf{Q}_\gamma\mathbf{Q}^\beta=
\eta^{\alpha \beta}\mathbf{Q}_\alpha\mathbf{Q}_\beta$

so that the dot-product between the metric tensor and another tensor of any order, shown here for a vector $\mathbf{v} = v^\nu \mathbf{Q}_\nu$, reads

$\mathbb{\eta}\hspace{-4pt}\mathbb{\eta} \cdot \mathbf{v} =
 \delta^{\alpha }_{\beta}\mathbf{Q}_\alpha\mathbf{Q}^\beta \cdot v^\nu \mathbf{Q}_\nu =
\delta^{\alpha }_{\beta}\mathbf{Q}_\alpha \cdot v^\nu \delta^\beta_\nu =
v^\alpha \mathbf{Q}_\alpha = \mathbf{v}$,

and thus the action of the metric tensor of the spacetime on a tensor of a spacetime acts as the identity.

Answer (score 0):

The identity tensor is defined such that for a given tensor, it yields that same tensor,
$$\mathbb{I}\mathsf{A}=\mathsf{A}.$$
When $\mathsf{A}$ is a rank-1 tensor (e.g., a vector), we associate this operation with the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta): $\delta^i_{\,\,j}=[i=j]$ (using the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) definition for convenience).

When considering higher ranks, it becomes slightly more complicated. For example, consider $\mathsf{A}=A_{ab}$. In this case, we must have,
$$\mathbb{I}^{ab}_{\,\,\,cd}A_{ab}=A_{cd}\implies\mathbb{I}^{ab}_{\,\,\,cd}\equiv\delta^{a}_{\,\,c}\delta^{b}_{\,\,d},$$
that is it is a product of Kronecker deltas. Similar relations can be obtained for higher ranks.

Answer (score 0):

The identity matrix is a mathematical constant, it is always $\operatorname{diag}(1, 1, \ldots)$. But *metric tensor* components in special relativity are not equal to identity matrix. If we have two 4-vectors $A^\mu$ and $B^\nu$, they scalar product is $g_{\mu \nu} A^\mu B^\nu$. Here $g_{\mu \nu}$ is so-called metric tensor, and its components are $\operatorname{diag}(1, -1, -1, -1)$ or $\operatorname{diag}(1, -1, -1, -1)$ depending on the agreement.